# Gsub Data frame Replace only exact Cell value matches, no substring

Tags: regex, r, lapply, gsub

The problem I am facing is that I have a dataframe called uniqindex which looks like the following.

```
S5  1   Below 25
S5  2   25-30
S5  3   31-35
S5  4   36-40 
S5  5   41-45
S5  6   46-50
```

A sample line of the file where I intend to replace the numeric codes with the age ranges looks like -

```
S5  4   3   5   3   7   4   3   4   4   7
```

Following is the code that I run

```
range<-c('S1','S2a','S2b','S4','S5','S5a','S6','S8','S9','Q8')
FinalOut<-NULL
AddColName<-NULL
for (y in range)
{
    df<-copytrans1[copytrans1[,1]==as.character(y),]
    uniqindex<-index1[index1[,1]==y,]
    looptime<-nrow(uniqindex)

                         for (k in 1:looptime)
                         {

 df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, FUN = function(x)                                                                  gsub(uniqindex[k,2],uniqindex[k,3], x)))
                          }
 FinalOut<-rbind(FinalOut,df)     
AddColName<-rbind(AddColName,cbind(as.data.frame(y),df))
}
```

The problem that I face is that as the substitutions run sequentially, this is the output that I get

```
S5a S5a ageage41_501_40 ageage41_501_40 age41_50    ageage41_501_40 age41_50    ageage41_501_40 ageage41_501_40 ageage41_501_40 ageage41_501_40 age41_50    age41_50
```

I want to know how can I change my code to only change exact matches. Currently, 1 would be changed to 25-30 and in the second iteration 2 of 25-30 is changed to 25-305-30

Comment: check if  `gsub(paste0("^",uniqindex[k,2],"$),uniqindex[k,3], x)))` will work

Comment: if what you want to do is change the index with the name of the classes, one way is: `uniqindex[your_line, 3]` (if the names of the classes are in the 3rd column)

Comment: @Deena Doesn't work. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

To match the one-digit index only as an isolated *word* rather than within a two-digit age, you can put the symbols `\<` and `\>` at the beginning and end of the pattern:

```
gsub(paste('\\<', uniqindex[k,2], '\\>', sep=''), uniqindex[k,3], x)
```